# How to troubleshoot linux iptable portforwarding

Tags: ssh, iptables, linux-networking, ssh-tunnel

There's already tons of help and guide on how to do this. But for some reason I can't get it working and am not sure how to troubleshoot it.
I've got an RDS postgres instance with the private IP `10.0.122.220`. I also have a bastion host with a (yes) private IP `10.0.94.67`. I'm able to connect to ports on the bastion host, but not the RDS. So I'm trying to forward port `5432` of the bastion host to port `5432` of the RDS instance.
This is the status of the bastion host:

```
bastion$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
...
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.94.67/19 brd 10.0.95.255 scope global dynamic eth0
...

bastion$ ip route show | grep default
default via 10.0.64.1 dev eth0

bastion$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Then I added two NAT rules:

```
bastion# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 5432 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.122.220

bastion# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 5432 -d 10.0.122.220 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.94.67

bastion# iptables -v -t nat -L -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5432 to:10.0.122.220

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 443 packets, 32660 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 443 packets, 32660 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 SNAT       tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            10.0.122.220         tcp dpt:5432 to:10.0.94.67
```

But I still can't connect to the RDS instance with the help of SSH tunneling:

```
my-machine$ ssh -v -NL 5432:10.0.94.67:5432 -i my-key ec2-user@10.0.94.67
debug1: Connection to port 5432 forwarding to 10.0.94.67 port 5432 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 5432 for 10.0.94.67 port 5432, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 57447 to 127.0.0.1 port 5432, nchannels 3
debug1: Connection to port 5432 forwarding to 10.0.94.67 port 5432 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 5432 for 10.0.94.67 port 5432, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 57448 to 127.0.0.1 port 5432, nchannels 3
... keeps repeating the above
```

What I can confirm is that, RDS is up, running, and responding, and bastion host has access to it, since with the following SSH tunnle I can connect to the database:

```
my-machine$ ssh -v -NL 5432:10.0.122.220:5432 -i my-key ec2-user@10.0.94.67
```

What did I miss? How can I troubleshoot it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you double check the netmasks on both server to not have a too large one ? Add a '-v' option to your "iptables -L -n' command, will show you counters. If it stay to 0, the rule is not applied. Add logs at the end of your rules to debug the packets

Comment: @Dom updated the post.

Comment: Sorry : iptables -L -nv -t nat (else it display the filter rules, which are empty)

Comment: @Dom NP. That was actually a question for me (why it doesn't show anything without `-t nat`). Updated the question.

Comment: I'm not an expert, can you please guide how to do the logging (any page to read or something)?

Comment: To add logging : iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j LOG --log-prefix 'PREROUTING: ', then check in your /var/log/kern.log file. The new rule will be added at the end of the PREROUTING chain. You may want to do that  too in POSTROUTING (if needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling that you are overcomplicating the things. As you are using SSH to forward the connection to the database, forget about iptables and NAT and just use SSH to forward DIRECTLY to the database server:

Use:

```
my-machine$ ssh -v -NL 5432:10.0.122.220:5432 -i my-key ec2-user@10.0.94.67
```

instead of:

```
my-machine$ ssh -v -NL 5432:10.0.94.67:5432 -i my-key ec2-user@10.0.94.67
```

Explanation why your solution DOESN'T work: The locally generated traffic does NOT go through PREROUTING chain of NAT table so it is NOT DNATted. Use OUTPUT table to DNAT locally generated traffic:

```
bastion# iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.122.220
```

But as I said - it is overcomplicating things. And you may also want to match on destination address in the above rule if you choose to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The ultimate solution is not based on ssh (but AWS SSM). At the moment I'm using it for troubleshooting. Regarding your explanation, good point. So you're saying that because I'm using the same host to make a tunnel, it's a local traffic and won't go through PREROUTING. I used a different instance in the same network as a jump server and yes, it worked. But the number of PREROUTING packets (in `iptables -v -t nat -L`) is still 0. Can you please comment on that?

Comment: As said, not an iptable expert, can you please elaborate on matching on destination comment? thanks.

Comment: How many interfaces do you have? Are you sure the traffic comes in through eth0?

Comment: Lookback + eth0 (the output of `ip a` shows only two entries).

Comment: Regarding the packets number, I think I looked at the wrong number (`Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)`. In the entry in the column `pkts` it shows some number.